# Finding integer coefficients in a quadratic equation

Tags: roots, quadratics

Question:

Let $ \ 2 $ be the only root of the following quadratic equation $ \ x^2 + px + q = 0$ with integer coefficients $ \ p$ and $ \ q$. Determine the numeral values for both $ \ p $ and $ \ q$.

My attempt:

Since the equation has only one root $ \ b^2 -4ac = 0$. So, $ \ p^2 - 4q = 0$. Now should I find $ p$ and $ \ q$ that satisfy this?

Comment: `Since the equation has only one root` ...and since it's a monic polynomial, it must be of the form $(x-a)^2=0\,$ for some $\,a\,$ (which you know already).

Comment: To continue from where you left off, I would suggest plugging in $2$ for $x$ - that is, $2^2 + 2*p + q = 0$. That should give you $q$ in terms of $p$, which in turn should leave you with a quadratic equation of $p$. That should tell you what $p$ is, and, subsequently, what $q$ is.